# Array Binding simple example doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I'm very new to `xaml` and I'm trying to understand the `Binding` issue. I have a problem with the `Array Binding`. I created this very simple example: I have a stack panel with three images. Each image has a `RotationTransform`. Each `Angle` is obtained by an array element (the array is a `DependencyProperty` called `Rotations`). This is the xaml simple file:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image Source="/Assets/knife.png" Width="50" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=Rotations[0], Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="/Assets/fork.png" Width="50" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=Rotations[1], Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="/Assets/spoon.png" Width="50" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=Rotations[2], Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

        <Button x:Name="actionButton" Content="Try Binding!" 
                Click="Op_Click"/>            
    </StackPanel>
```

And this is my `c#` class:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {        
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rotations", typeof(double[]), typeof(MainPage),
            new PropertyMetadata(new double[3]));

        public double[] Rotations
        {
            get { return (double[])GetValue(RotationsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RotationsProperty, value); }
        }

        private void Op_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Rotations[0] = 180;
            Rotations[1] = 130;
            Rotations[2] = 350;
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Rotations[0] = 20;
            Rotations[1] = 90;
            Rotations[2] = 180;
        }
    }
```

The binding works only the first time (at startup time). When I click on the button (changing the Rotations array) the binding doesn't work and it is completely ignored from my images.

This is a very simple example, so it's clear that I miss something concerning the Binding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution using `ObservableCollection`: the `xaml` file remains the same, but the `c#` class changes this way:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {        
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationsProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("Rotations", typeof(ObservableCollection<double>), typeof(MainPage),
            new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<double>()));       

        public ObservableCollection<double> Rotations
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<double>)GetValue(RotationsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RotationsProperty, value); }
        }

        private void Op_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Rotations[0] = 180;
            Rotations[1] = 180;
            Rotations[2] = 320;
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Rotations.Add(90);
            Rotations.Add(90);
            Rotations.Add(90);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you change the value of the array entries, but you don't change the array itself, so 'SetValue' does not get called. You could try to set 'Rotations' to a new array.

```
this.Rotations = new double[] {180, 130, 350};
```

Edit: I tested your code with my changes and it worked. Another suggestion would be to write a setter method for the array entries and call 'SetValue' or (like suggested in the comments) use 'INotifyPropertyChanged' instead of a DependencyProperty.

Comment: Mmh... I'll try in a moment, but this is very weird... do I have to generate a new array each time I modify an element? This is crazy :) Isn't there any other method to to this?

Comment: you should use the interface  INotifyPropertyChanged  , after updating the Array members raise the event  using the property name as the parameter

Comment: Or he could keep the DependencyProperty and just write a setter method to update an array value and call SetValue afterwards.

Comment: @stsur: no need to use INotifyPropertyChanged, check my own answer. I upvoted lukegv answer because it works, but it's very inefficient.

Comment: I know, but I tried to get your project work without big changes. You used an array and I wanted to show you that you need to update the array itself, because there is no notification if an array entry gets changed, but for sure my solution is not "beautiful" programming ;)

Comment: Yes, and this is why I upvoted your answer :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Image Source="/Assets/knife.png" Width="50" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Rotations[0], Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

    <Image Source="/Assets/fork.png" Width="50" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Rotations[1], Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

    <Image Source="/Assets/spoon.png" Width="50" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Rotations[2], Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

    <Button x:Name="actionButton" Content="Try Binding!" 
            Click="Op_Click"/>            
</StackPanel>
```

In the code behind set the DataContext as below :

this.DataContext = this;